XSD format issue
I'm using Azure Logic Apps to retrieve data from MS Dynamics Business Central. This data is transformed into an XML using an XSD format. The XML is then send to an external system.
I managed to get most of the process working but i'm still experiencing an issue with a section of the XSD. The data consists of a header, this section only appears once at the top of the xml, and one or multiple orderlines. The orderlines should appear multiple times but instead the data for multiple orderlines is added into one block.
I've added exampels for the xsd, the xml as it should appear and the xml as it appears now.
The XSD
<xs:element name="orderlines">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="orderline" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="whs" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="qty" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="partnr" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="snr" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="refnr" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="origincountry" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="commercialvalue" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="commoditycode" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

The XML as it's expected
<orderlines>
    <orderline>
        <type>REPLENISH</type>
        <whs>tes</whs>
        <qty>50</qty>
        <partnr>201.9004.8</partnr>
        <snr></snr>
        <refnr>efa79477-dfec-ee11-a1fd-7c1e52208373</refnr>
        <origincountry></origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>191.25</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode></commoditycode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <type>REPLENISH</type>
        <whs>tes</whs>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <partnr>300.1351.1</partnr>
        <snr></snr>
        <refnr>b50570f3-7e7a-ef11-a671-6045bd999b21</refnr>
        <origincountry></origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>50.75</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode></commoditycode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <type>REPLENISH</type>
        <whs>tes</whs>
        <qty>50</qty>
        <partnr>201.9004.8</partnr>
        <snr></snr>
        <refnr>1538e880-f9f0-ee11-a1fd-0022489bf1a3</refnr>
        <origincountry></origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>191.24</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode></commoditycode>
    </orderline>
</orderlines>

The XML output i'm getting now
<orderlines>
    <orderline>
        <type>["REPLENISH"]</type>
        <whs>["tes","tes","tes","tes"]</whs>
        <qty>[50,1,50,50]</qty>
        <partnr>["201.9004.8","300.1351.1","201.9004.8","201.9004.8"]</partnr>
        <snr>[]</snr>
        <refnr>
            ["efa79477-dfec-ee11-a1fd-7c1e52208373","b50570f3-7e7a-ef11-a671-6045bd999b21","1538e880-f9f0-ee11-a1fd-0022489bf1a3","4438e880-f9f0-ee11-a1fd-0022489bf1a3"]</refnr>
        <origincountry>[]</origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>[191.25,50.75,191.24,191.24]</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode>[]</commoditycode>
    </orderline>
</orderlines>

Would love some help, thanks in advance!

Are you using Transform XML action?

Is your input data in Json format> @jandemul

@IkhtesamAfrin no i'm using the "xml compose with schema". as to your second question, yes I suppose so. json is logic apps prefered format.

Can you share your input data and workflow screenshot? @jandemul

JSON doesn't have strong validation that would match XML XSD 1.1 business rules powers.

I have used the below input data in XML compose with schema action with the given schema.
Input Data :-
[
    {
      "type": "REPLENISH",
      "whs": "tes",
      "qty": "50",
      "partnr": "201.9004.8",
      "snr": "",
      "refnr": "efa79477-dfec-ee11-a1fd-7c1e52208373",
      "origincountry": "",
      "commercialvalue": "191.25",
      "commoditycode": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "REPLENISH",
      "whs": "tes",
      "qty": "1",
      "partnr": "300.1351.1",
      "snr": "",
      "refnr": "b50570f3-7e7a-ef11-a671-6045bd999b21",
      "origincountry": "",
      "commercialvalue": "50.75",
      "commoditycode": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "REPLENISH",
      "whs": "tes",
      "qty": "50",
      "partnr": "201.9004.8",
      "snr": "",
      "refnr": "1538e880-f9f0-ee11-a1fd-0022489bf1a3",
      "origincountry": "",
      "commercialvalue": "191.24",
      "commoditycode": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "REPLENISH",
      "whs": "tes",
      "qty": "50",
      "partnr": "201.9004.8",
      "snr": "",
      "refnr": "4438e880-f9f0-ee11-a1fd-0022489bf1a3",
      "origincountry": "",
      "commercialvalue": "191.24",
      "commoditycode": ""
    }
]

Schema :-
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="orderlines">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="orderline" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="whs" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="qty" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="partnr" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="snr" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="refnr" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="origincountry" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="commercialvalue" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="commoditycode" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


I have got expected response.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<orderlines>
    <orderline>
        <type>REPLENISH</type>
        <whs>tes</whs>
        <qty>50</qty>
        <partnr>201.9004.8</partnr>
        <snr></snr>
        <refnr>efa79477-dfec-ee11-a1fd-7c1e52208373</refnr>
        <origincountry></origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>191.25</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode></commoditycode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <type>REPLENISH</type>
        <whs>tes</whs>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <partnr>300.1351.1</partnr>
        <snr></snr>
        <refnr>b50570f3-7e7a-ef11-a671-6045bd999b21</refnr>
        <origincountry></origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>50.75</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode></commoditycode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <type>REPLENISH</type>
        <whs>tes</whs>
        <qty>50</qty>
        <partnr>201.9004.8</partnr>
        <snr></snr>
        <refnr>1538e880-f9f0-ee11-a1fd-0022489bf1a3</refnr>
        <origincountry></origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>191.24</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode></commoditycode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <type>REPLENISH</type>
        <whs>tes</whs>
        <qty>50</qty>
        <partnr>201.9004.8</partnr>
        <snr></snr>
        <refnr>4438e880-f9f0-ee11-a1fd-0022489bf1a3</refnr>
        <origincountry></origincountry>
        <commercialvalue>191.24</commercialvalue>
        <commoditycode></commoditycode>
    </orderline>
</orderlines>


This issue has been resolved. Instead of setting up the .xsd as above I've set it up as seen below.


<xs:element name="orderlines">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="orderline" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>



enter image description here
This allows me to setup a variable in the logic app as shown below as input for the "Orderline"
